# Induction trouble

Tags: calculus

I can`t find the key to solve this induction problem: Let $a_1,a_2, \ldots, a_n$ be positive real numbers and let
$$A_n = \frac{1}{n}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i$$
be its arithmetic mean. Show 
$$n \geq 2:\quad A_{n}^{n} \geq A_{n-1}^{n-1} a_n$$

The proof must not use the AM-GM inequality only induction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$A_n^n \geq A_{n-1}^{n-1}(n A_n-(n-1)A_{n-1})=n A_n A_{n-1}^{n-1}-(n-1)A_{n-1}^n$$
is equivalent to:
$$ A_n^n- A_{n-1}^n \geq n A_{n-1}^{n-1} (A_n-A_{n-1})$$
or to:
$$ \underbrace{A_n^{n-1}+ A_n^{n-2}A_{n-1} + \ldots + A_n A_{n-1}^{n-2} + A_{n-1}^{n-1}}_{n\text{ terms}} \geq n A_{n-1}^{n-1}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint but I don't know how apply the induction hypothesis to this form.